# How do I type cast multi type ListView items in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a ListView builder that builds a list. I would like first item in the list to be built from a different list item as the rest.

***I add the first item to an array:***

```
NoteModel? noteData;
List<NoteModel>? notesData = [];
notesData?.insert(0, widget.note);
```

***I created a dynamic list:***

```
List<dynamic>? listData = [];
```

***After API response I add the item to the list:***

```
var newList = {...?notesData, ...state.comments}.toList();
```

***Inside my List Builder I do:***

```
child: ListView.builder(
  itemCount: listData?.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    if (index == 0) {
      return NoteBubble(
        notes: listData as List<NoteModel>,
        note: listData![index] as NoteModel,
        index: index,
      );
    }

    return CommentBubble(
      comments: listData as List<CommentModel>,
      comment: listData![index] as CommentModel,
      className: className,
      index: index,
    );
  },
),
```

This doesn't complain until I run the app and it throws errors.

***What I tried:***

I have tried many manipulations of types including what I have placed below. The following error is thrown. It is basically complaining about the line of code with "notes: listData as dynamic".

> type List Object is not a subtype of type List NoteModel

```
child: ListView.builder(
  itemCount: listData?.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    if (index == 0) {
      return NoteBubble(
        notes: listData as dynamic,
        note: listData![index] as dynamic,
        index: index,
      );
    }

    return CommentBubble(
      comments: listData as dynamic,
      comment: listData![index] as dynamic,
      className: className,
      index: index,
    );
  },
),
```

UPDATE!!! I have added this code because I was able to get this working by changing the List NoteModel and List CommentModel to List dynamic and it works. I am adding this in case someone knows a better way since this feels hackish

***NoteBubble Class***

class NoteBubble extends StatelessWidget {

```
  final Function? onPlay;
  final Function? onPlayNote;

  final List<CommentModel>? comments;
  final List<NoteModel> notes;
  final NoteModel note;
  final int index;

  const NoteBubble({
    super.key,
    this.onPlay,
    this.onPlayNote,
    this.comments,
    required this.notes,
    required this.note,
    required this.index,
  });
```

***CommentBubble Class:***

```
class CommentBubble extends StatelessWidget {
  final String? className;
  final Function? onPlay;
  final bool? player;

  final List<CommentModel> comments;
  final CommentModel comment;
  final int index;

  const CommentBubble({
    super.key,
    this.className,
    this.onPlay,
    this.player,
    required this.comments,
    required this.comment,
    required this.index,
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to do your verification on the type of the element of the list.

```
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: listData?.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    if (listData!.first.runtimeType == NoteModel) { // <= this
      return NoteBubble(
        notes: listData,
        note: listData![index],
        index: index,
      );
    }

    return CommentBubble(
      comments: listData,
      comment: listData![index],
      className: className,
      index: index,
    );
  },
);
```

Comment: I like your check better than mine checking for 0, but it still has the same complaint. It seems to really hate  final List<NoteModel> notes in the NoteBubble widget. I really don't like the solution of changing that to dynamic since this widget is used elsewhere